# paperclip with devise uploading to s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, devise, mongoid, paperclip

I have a rest api that I am building.  It uses `mongoid`, `devise` and now has `paperclip` `mongoid-paperclip` and `aws-sdk` gems installed

`Gemfile.rb`

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :docgi
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'rspec-its', '~> 1.2.0'
gem 'unicorn', '~> 4.9.0'
gem 'kaminari' # adds pagination to ActiveModels
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'simple_token_authentication', '~> 1.9.1'
gem 'cancancan'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.1'
gem "mongoid-paperclip", :require => "mongoid_paperclip"
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
```

My user model uses all of this like so:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paperclip
  has_many :posts
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :passive_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"

  validates :email, presence: true,
            uniqueness: true,
            format: {
                with: /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\Z/
            }
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :telephone, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :gender, presence: true
  validates :dob, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true
  has_mongoid_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" },
                            :storage => :s3,
                            :s3_credentials => {
                                :bucket => 'app-imgs/profile',
                                :access_key_id => "key",
                                :secret_access_key => "+t0v4+key1"
                            },
                            :url => "app-imgs.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
                            :path => "/:id/:style_:origin_timestamp",
                            :use_timestamp => true
  validates_attachment_content_type :picture, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :trackable, :validatable
  ## Token Authenticatable
  acts_as_token_authenticatable
  field :authentication_token

  ## Profile
  field :name,               type: String, default: ""
  field :gender,             type: String
  field :dob,                type: Date
  field :telephone,          type: String
  field :username,           type: String
  field :last_action,        type: Time
  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,              type: String, default: ""
  field :encrypted_password, type: String, default: ""

  ## Trackable
  field :sign_in_count,      type: Integer, default: 0
  field :current_sign_in_at, type: Time
  field :last_sign_in_at,    type: Time
  field :current_sign_in_ip, type: String
  field :last_sign_in_ip,    type: String

  ## Indexes
  index({ email: 1, username: 1 })
  index({ last_location: "2d" }, { min: -200, max: 200 })
  index({ gender: 1, dob: 1, telephone: 1, loc: -1, posts: -1})


end
```

I then created a paperclip initializer to deal with interpolation:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:filename] = DateTime.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
Paperclip.interpolates ('origin_timestamp') do |style, attachment|
  DateTime.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
end
```

for my devise in my routes i added:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations', :sessions => 'sessions'}
```

I overrode the devise create function like so:

```
def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    resource_saved = resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_saved
      sign_up(resource_name, resource)
      render json: resource
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      render json: resource.errors
      # @validatable = devise_mapping.validatable?
      # if @validatable
      #   @minimum_password_length = resource_class.password_length.min
      # end
      # respond_with resource
    end
  end
 private
  def sign_up_params
    params.permit(:name, :gender, :dob, :telephone, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :picture)
  end
```

Now when I start my `rails s` and use postman to simulate a user signup I get the following errors:

```
, [2015-05-22T13:57:31.529648 #27393]  INFO -- : [paperclip] saving 555f983b6a75736b01030000/original_20150522135731
[AWS S3 403 0.382363 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"app-imgs/profile",:content_length=>107729,:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter: upsellPanel.jpg,:key=>"555f983b6a75736b01030000/original_20150522135731") AWS::S3::Errors::AllAccessDisabled All access to this object has been disabled

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 576ms

AWS::S3::Errors::AllAccessDisabled (All access to this object has been disabled):
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:17:in `create'
```

I've been searching and can't figure out a resolution to this issue.  I copied configuration over from my remote server to my localhost.  I know that it works in at least one respect in that I can type `aws s3 ls` in the terminal and it'll show me my buckets.

Answer (score 0):

The bucket-name is showing :bucket_name=>"app-imgs/profile" , correct it.

Comment: But that is correct.  Where I want it uploaded it app-imgs bucket, in the subfolder of profile